# Facebook Marketing API Select Fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to get only offiste conversions within this marketing api call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<ad_id>/insights?fields=actions{"action_type":{"offsite_conversion"}}&access_token=<token>
```

but i get all fields in "actions". any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter:**"filtering"**

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/**ad_id**/insights?
&fields=actions&action_breakdowns=action_type
&filtering={{"field":"action_type","operator":"CONTAIN","value":"offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_complete_registration"}]&access_token=**token**