# Is there a way to get custom conversion data for each ads through Facebook marketing API?

Tags: facebook, api

Found this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-conversion/

but it doesn't help me.

I'm trying to get the 'custom conversion' data for each ads but according to the ref. above I can the number for each custom conversion (not separate for each ads).

Any idea ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave describes the custom conversion object itself (not related to any ad). For individual ad's conversion data you would look at the insights:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.9

Specifically, query the `actions` field and filter by `action_type` (refer to the `filtering` parameter on `insights` for how to do filtering https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v2.9)

And this answer has a concrete example:
[Facebook Marketing API Select Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660339/facebook-marketing-api-select-fields)